# How do you include images as resources in a C++ executable?

Tags: c++, windows, resources

Is it possible include images (jpegs) as resources in a win32 c++ executable?  If so how?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. An image is not runnable code and "compiling" it to an executable is thus undefined. What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: OS dependent, and not even well defined on all platforms, And where possible not a feature of and particular language.

Comment: Seems this is a questions about win32 only (based on the answer currently accepted). Perhaps the question should be updated to reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the MSDN documentation about resource files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380599(VS.85).aspx

Comment: many thanks, I was searching for the wrong term (compiling images into  exe)

Answer (score 5):

If it's Windows only then use a custom resource.  If you want something cross-platform then do what I did for a recent project - create an app that will encode the JPEG as a `char*` buffer in a header file and then include these headers in your main project.  You will also need to store the size of the buffer as it will be sure to contain NULs.

For example, I have an app that you can pass a load of files to be encoded and for each file you get a header file that looks something like this:

```
#ifndef RESOURCE_SOMEFILE_JPG_HPP
#define RESOURCE_SOMEFILE_JPG_HPP

namespace resource {

const char* SOMEFILE_JPG[] =
{
  ...raw jpeg data...
};

const int SOMEFILE_JPG_LEN = 1234;

} // resource

#endif // RESOURCE_SOMEFILE_JPG_HPP
```

The app has to escape special non-printable chars in `\x` format, but it's pretty simple.  The app uses the `boost::program_options` library so a list of files to encode can be stored in a config file.  Each file gets its own header like similar to the above.

However, be warned - this only works for small files as some compilers have a limit on the maximum size a static char buffer can be.  I'm sure there are other ways to do this but this scheme works for me (a C++ web app that stores the HTML, CSS, JavaScript and image files in this way).

Comment: This is what QT does for cross platform resources.

Comment: A reasonable to store this kind of data. Gets my vote. But it loses some of the features that make "resources" a good idea on platforms that support them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/load_jpeg__gif_resource.aspx) is what you're looking for?