# Platform independent resource system (like the Qt Resource system)

Tags: c++, resources, embedded-resource

Is there a platform independent resource system for C++ like the one that comes with Qt (but without the Qt dependency)?

I would like to access arbitrary data from within my C++ source code. That is, not only icons but also translations or shaders, etc.

Alternatively some sort of virtual file system library to access e.g. a ZIP compressed file or such would also fit my needs.

Comment: Do the resources have to be embedded in your executable?  If not then another path could be using SQLite to store the files - getting up and running with this lightweight database wouldn't be too much effort.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549031/how-do-you-include-images-as-resources-in-a-c-executable

Answer (score 9):

I rolled my own system for a C++ web server project that basically took a bunch of files (HTML, CSS, JS, PNGs, etc.) and created C++ headers containing the data encoded as `static const char*`.  I then `#include` those headers where I need access to the data.  The app that encodes the 'resource' files executes as a pre-build step.  The encoding app itself used `boost::filesystem` to create the resource headers, so works on Windows/*nix.

A typical resource file might look like this:

```
namespace resource
{
  // Generated from mainPage.htm
  static const char* mainPage_[] =
  {
    "<html>...</html>"
  };
}
```

For binary content I encode using the `\x` notation.  I also make sure to line-wrap the data so it is readable in an editor.

I did have some issues though - the MS compiler doesn't allow a `static const char*` to be bigger than 64Kb which was a PITA.  Luckily the only files larger than this were JavaScript files that I could easily split into smaller chunks - large images would be a problem though.

Comment: Because I couldn't find a cross-platform Qt-like resource system, that's why.  I gave the question a sensible answer and you voted me down?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `xxd` answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656968/platform-independant-resource-management) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We're using [ICU ResourceBundle](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/resources)s for that and are pretty satisfied with it.

Using the [pkgdata tool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/pkgdata.1.html), packageing of ResourceBundles is pretty flexible: as a shared library, static library, or as files that can be memory-mapped by ICU.

Answer (score 0):

I have just patched them onto the end of the executable at link time as a binary blob. With the last 4bytes being the size of the previous block and then have the program read the data items from the tail.

Another approach if you need a more filesystem type structure (though I havem't tried it) would be to put everything in a zip file and append that to the end. Again you would need some easily findabale size of the added data.